# tkinter module not found

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

So Im about to run Kohya_ss, when I run it, I get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'`.

I tried `pip install tk` and it says that this demand is already satisfied.
I did some research and I tried some pip-commands like `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tk`, `pip install python3-tk` but nothing seems to work.

I wrote a test.py outside of the Kohya_ss environment and I still get the error. Im using python 3.10.11.

I found similar problems on StackOverflow, but sady their solutions didnt work for me.

Comment: You can't install tkinter with pip. When you install `tk` you are installing tensorkit, not tkinter.

Comment: Okay, at least a little hint. I googled it and many users postet pip commands like this one.

Comment: `tkinter` is a built in module. you **do not** need to `pip install` it. The docs are here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html